# Parameterized query for inserting values

Tags: c#, c, ms-access, oledb

I was trying to insert values into an Access database using a parameterized query:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (validationcontrol())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(cmbjobcode.SelectedValue.ToString());
                OleDbConnection oleDbConnection1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString);
                oleDbConnection1.Open();
                OleDbCommand oleDbCommand1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO quotationmastertable (quotationcode ,jobcode , jobpk , sillabordercharges , battabordercharges , driverpayment , rent , extra , total , discount , remark ,amount ) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ", oleDbConnection1);
                oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(txtquotationno.Text);
                oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(cmbjobcode.Text);
                oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(cmbjobcode.SelectedValue);
                oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(int.Parse(txtsilabordercharges.Text));
                oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(int.Parse(txtbattacharges.Text));
                oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(int.Parse(txtdriverpayment.Text));
                oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(int.Parse(txtrent.Text));
                oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(int.Parse(txtextra.Text));
                oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(int.Parse(txttotal.Text));
                oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(int.Parse(txtdiscount.Text));
                oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(txtremark.Text);
                oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(int.Parse(txtamount.Text));
                oleDbCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                oleDbCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                oleDbConnection1.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(txtquotationno.Text);

            }
        }
```

but I am getting an exception at the first line itself:

```
oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add(txtquotationno.Text);
```

The exception is

> The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects.

I am new to programming; can anyone help in pointing out my mistakes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single parameter for the `Add` object is expecting an OleDBParameter object.  You are just passing strings and data.

A simple fix would be to use the `AddWithValue` method:

```
oleDbCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtquotationno.Text);
oleDbCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cmbjobcode.Text);
```

OleDB does not really use parameter names, it's index based, which is why you can pass the question mark for each one of your parameters as the name.  You **do** have to make sure your parameters are in the same order as your query statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are tryng to add a string to a collection of parameters. Try this (changing  `OleDbType.VarChar, 50` to the actual type of the data column in your db.

```
oleDbCommand1.Parameters.Add("@quot", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value =  txtquotationno.Text;
```

See the msdn for an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx