# Displaying multiple values in datagridview by filter searching

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I was making a vb program that searches a student info by searching a course.. For example Ajax's course is "BSCS" and DP's course is "BSIT" , then i'm going to select BSCS, so Ajax's must only appear not DP. The result appear's in DataGridView

```
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE (Course = '" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()
        FirstNameTextBox = dr("FirstName")
        MiddleNameTextBox = dr("MiddleName")
        LastNameTextBox = dr("LastName")
        AddressTextBox = dr("Address")
        CellphoneNumberTextBox = dr("CellphoneNumber")
        CourseTextBox = dr("Course")
    End While
    myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: You need to fill a `DataTable` and then set that to your `DataGridView` as the `DataSource`. As of right now these results are not going to the `DataGridView`.

Comment: Beware of sql injection - you should never build your query by concatenating text values from users. Instead use parameterized queries as seen in these examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12048152/3773066) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9401888/3773066).

Comment: SQL injection in action: https://www.xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Code you should add new DataGridView to your form and also adding columns with header name that you choose and replace the code with mine

```
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE (Course = '" & TextBox1.Text & "')"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read()
           DataGridView1.Rows.Add({dr("FirstName"),  dr("MiddleName"), dr("LastName"), dr("Address"), dr("CellphoneNumber"), dr("Course")})
        End While
        myConnection.Close()
```